# what is a path which visits every vertex at least once called

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-cycle

As I understand it, a Hamiltonian path visits every vertex of a graph exactly once.
Is there a name for a path which visits every vertex at least once?

Some graphs may be such that a cycle visiting every vertex, must visit some
vertices more than once.   I'd like to talk about the shortest such cycles.

Comment: Since this question is purely about discrete mathematics, not programming or computer science specifically, it would be better asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK, done.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049861/what-is-a-path-called-that-visits-every-vertex-of-a-graph-at-least-once?noredirect=1#comment8364429_4049861